# Syncing browser control display with HTML source code display

Tags: navigation, vb6, webbrowser-control

I have a VB6 program for viewing/editing HTML files which displays a local HTML page ("Web page" - can't think of a better name for it) on the left half of the screen and the HTML code on the right half using the MS browser control.

When clicking on an internal link on the Web page, I can interrupt at *brwWebBrowser_Before Navigate* to get the link ID at the end of the URL and then search in the HTML code for that ID and bring that up on the right display to match the Web page on the left display.

The problem is that if I navigate back by clicking on the left arrow, there's nothing in BeforeNavigate to indicate where in the Web page it is going, so the code window doesn't move with it.

I figured I need to determine the page it is on before it leaves it in the first place, but can't think of a way to do that.  Am I overlooking something obvious?

Comment: If you have total control over what HTML gets loaded, can't you manually store the  series of locations being displayed (maybe as a stack), and then navigate backward by popping items off of that?

Comment: You're right. And I was overlooking the obvious. I lost sight of the fact that I have the ID from the link they clicked on. What a dope!  Thanks.